# Can't track heap memory usage in my C program at runtime

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I took a look at similar question but it didn't serve my  purpose. My actual programme crashed due to increasing memory in "RES" section from "top" command in ubuntu linux which is why I wanted to track the memory leak. Here "RES" refers to the physical memory being used by the program at run time. So, I wrote a little programme to keep track of "RES" memory caused by malloc() and free() operation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define CAPACITY_DEBUG 1000000

void printMemUsage(){
    struct rusage usage;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    fprintf(stderr,"Memory usage: %ld KB .................\n", usage.ru_maxrss);
}

void MallocTest(){
    fprintf(stderr,"test 1 started ......................!!\n");
    printMemUsage();
    sleep(5);

    fprintf(stderr,"starting to allocate ....................\n");
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(CAPACITY_DEBUG * sizeof(int));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed. Exiting...\n");
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < CAPACITY_DEBUG; i++){
        arr[i] = 5;
    }
    printMemUsage();
    fprintf(stderr,"allocation done, going to sleep................\n");
    sleep(15);

    fprintf(stderr,"Woke up, starting to free............\n");
    free(arr); // Free the memory when you're done.
    // malloc_trim(0);
    fprintf(stderr,"free done................\n");
    sleep(5);
    printMemUsage();
}

void MallocTest2(){
    fprintf(stderr,"test 2 started ......................!!\n");
    printMemUsage();
    sleep(5);

    fprintf(stderr,"starting to allocate ....................\n");
    int* arr[CAPACITY_DEBUG];  // Declare an array of integer pointers
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY_DEBUG; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  // Allocate memory for each element
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            // Handle memory allocation failure
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Initialize the value in the allocated memory
        *arr[i] = i * 2;
    }
    printMemUsage();
    fprintf(stderr,"allocation done, going to sleep................\n");
    sleep(15);

    fprintf(stderr,"Woke up, starting to free............\n");
    // Don't forget to free the allocated memory when done
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY_DEBUG; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    //malloc_trim(0);
    fprintf(stderr,"free done................\n");
    sleep(30);
    printMemUsage();
}

int main(){

    MallocTest2();
    
    return 1;
}
```

here I simply used **printMemUsage()** function which actually portraits the **"RES" in "top" command** (correct me if I am wrong). the expected output is that, a low memory usage at start, then larger number after allocation and again low after free, right? here is the output :

```
$ ./memTest2 
test 2 started ......................!!
Memory usage: 2680 KB .................
starting to allocate ....................
Memory usage: 40560 KB .................
allocation done, going to sleep................
Woke up, starting to free............
free done................
Memory usage: 40560 KB .................
```

Here the usage shows a much larger amount of memory usage than actually allocated ones, and the problematic thing from my perspective is why the memory usage isn't being gone to the previous state after free().
What am I doing wrong here or what should I do to track things like this as I experienced similar kinda memory leak problem and that program crashed even after free() ?

Here is the output running the same program with **valgrind** :

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./memTest2
==104110== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==104110== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==104110== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==104110== Command: ./memTest2
==104110== 
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x25
### unhandled dwarf2 abbrev form code 0x1b
get_Form_szB: unhandled 27 (DW_FORM_addrx)
--104110-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--104110-- When reading debug info from /home/reve/reve_dpdk_v22.11.1_ubuntu_v22.04.2/projects/fuji_projects/dpdkbasic/memTest2:
--104110-- get_Form_contents: unhandled DW_FORM
==104110== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x1fff0002b8 --> 0x1ffe85f020
==104110==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=8000152 or greater
==104110== Invalid write of size 8
==104110==    at 0x109345: MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:83)
==104110==    by 0x10BDE7: ??? (in /home/reve/reve_dpdk_v22.11.1_ubuntu_v22.04.2/projects/fuji_projects/dpdkbasic/memTest2)
==104110==    by 0x1094B5: main (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:116)
==104110==  Address 0x1ffe85f018 is on thread 1's stack
==104110==  in frame #0, created by MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:82)
==104110== 
test 2 started ......................!!
==104110== Invalid read of size 8
==104110==    at 0x48E8026: fwrite (iofwrite.c:49)
==104110==    by 0x109349: MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:83)
==104110==    by 0x1094B5: main (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:116)
==104110==  Address 0x1ffe85f018 is on thread 1's stack
==104110==  in frame #0, created by fwrite (iofwrite.c:31)
==104110== 
==104110== Syscall param getrusage(usage) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==104110==    at 0x498254B: getrusage (getrusage.c:29)
==104110==    by 0x10935A: MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:17)
==104110==    by 0x1094B5: main (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:116)
==104110==  Address 0x1ffe85f0b0 is on thread 1's stack
==104110==  in frame #1, created by MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:82)
==104110== 
Memory usage: 55336 KB .................
starting to allocate ....................
==104110== Invalid write of size 8
==104110==    at 0x1093AA: MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:90)
==104110==    by 0x1094B5: main (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:116)
==104110==  Address 0x1ffe85f140 is on thread 1's stack
==104110==  in frame #0, created by MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:82)
==104110== 
==104110== Syscall param getrusage(usage) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==104110==    at 0x498254B: getrusage (getrusage.c:29)
==104110==    by 0x1093D5: MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:17)
==104110==    by 0x1094B5: main (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:116)
==104110==  Address 0x1ffe85f020 is on thread 1's stack
==104110==  in frame #1, created by MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:82)
==104110== 
Memory usage: 204140 KB .................
allocation done, going to sleep................
Woke up, starting to free............
==104110== Invalid read of size 8
==104110==    at 0x109430: MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:106)
==104110==    by 0x1094B5: main (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:116)
==104110==  Address 0x1ffe85f140 is on thread 1's stack
==104110==  in frame #0, created by MallocTest2 (src/media_queue_handler/queueTest.c:82)
==104110== 
free done................
Memory usage: 204140 KB .................
==104110== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x1ffe85f020 --> 0x1fff0002b8
==104110==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=8000152 or greater
==104110== 
==104110== HEAP SUMMARY:
==104110==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==104110==   total heap usage: 1,000,000 allocs, 1,000,000 frees, 4,000,000 bytes allocated
==104110== 
==104110== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==104110== 
==104110== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with -s
==104110== ERROR SUMMARY: 1999938 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `int* arr[CAPACITY_DEBUG];` would try to burn up 8Mb of stack space, which is probably more than your compiler is setup to provide for the executable... You may have to use a smaller number than 1 million pointers in this array...

Comment: @Fe2O3 ok I will lower the number, but why the mem usage not going to beginning state after freeing.. meaning "RES" stays same after free which caused crashing in one of my large program

Comment: Dunno... Stack overflow causes undefined behaviour... If you didn't realise a stack array of one million pointers would cause a problem, there's no way to tell what your "large program" might be trying to do...

Comment: if I lower the number then, the print mem usages stay the same always.. like I just used 1000 size and it stayed 2740 KB always, at beginning, after malloc and even after free.. and while running the same prog with valgrind it always remained same as 55416 KB. I just dont understand the behaviour

Comment: `free` does not have to return memory to the OS

Comment: in that case what happen to the program that need continious malloc ? will it overflow after certain period?